# Can I specify ruby version with patchlevel in Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gemfile

Bundler documentation for version `1.5` says that I should specify patchlevel as follows:

```
ruby '1.9.3', :patchlevel => 448
```

When I follow the instruction and run `bundle install`, I get:

```
The Ruby patchlevel in your Gemfile must be a string
```

If I do

```
ruby '2.0.0', :patchlevel => '353'
```

`Bundler` says:

```
ruby-2.0.0,:patchlevel=>353 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-2.0.0,:patchlevel=>353'
```

Is it even possible to specify ruby version with patchlevel in `Gemfile`?

Comment: have you tried running `rvm install ruby-2.0.0,:patchlevel=>353` like it says?

Comment: No, as there is no such version `ruby-2.0.0,:patchlevel=>353`.

Comment: That patch might be requiring a specific version of ruby , first install it and then include it in Gemfile .

Comment: I have ruby-2.0.0-p353. It is current and default. The problem is that `bundler` is looking for `ruby-2.0.0,:patchlevel=>353` which looks like a bug.

Comment: Are you doing this on Heroku?

Comment: No, but I would like `bundler` to select ruby version the way Heroku does.

Comment: I can only suggest: update or reinstall bundler. This does seem like a bundler issue.

Comment: `gem update bundler` (update from 1.5 to 1.6.2) did the trick. Patchlevel however has to be a string.

Answer (score 6):

`rvm install 2.0.0-p353` at the command line (in your shell) will do it for you.

You can specify the Ruby version in the Gemfile (Heroku does this) and it is OK, but it will only report, not install, the version problem.

So you would then have in your Gemfile:

`ruby '2.0.0', :patchlevel => '353'`

That will help RVM to determine which version of Ruby you should use.

Answer (score -1):

You don't install ruby with bundler. Use RVM for that.
It is used to specify a dependency on a specific ruby version/patchlevel.

Described [here](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile_ruby.html)

Comment: I have ruby. I need `ruby '2.0.0', :patchlevel => '353'` statement in `Gemfile` to select ruby version in production.

Comment: When you do `rvm list` does it contain `ruby-2.0.0-p353`?

Comment: Here is the output of `rvm list`: `=* ruby-2.0.0-p353 [ x86_64 ]`